# React axios request on socket.io backend emit

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'd like to use my axios get request "reload", when the server emit the serverchange listener.

The socket is working, I've got the "**msg**" from the server, and my code is working for a while, but every request is taking more time... The message is a UUID, so it's unique. (if it matters)

I'm pretty new in React even more in socket.io, so probably missing some logical step, I've spent half of my day to figure it out with no luck.

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_ENDPOINT)
    const cb = (msg) => setUpdate(msg)

    socket.on("serverchange", cb)
    return () => {
      socket.off("serverchange", cb)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/messages")
      .then((res) => setMessages(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  }, [update])
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the requests in the network tab?

Comment: Sure, thank you for you help. My code lives in the App.js so I made some kinf of bad loop or something... but I don't know where... https://1drv.ms/u/s!AofdGEB8vmWRhMlx_GJvh8BF1RR_Kg?e=NPs8KZ